# Type class variable in c#

Tags: c#, casting

How to cast using type variable ?
consider below code

```
public static object As(object o1, Type t1)
{
  return (t1)o1;
}
```

But it is showing me an error that t1 is a variable and is used as type. how can i achieve this purpose.Is it possible to retrieve the type from type object.I was asked to implement is and as operators in c# hence the method name.

Comment: Generics.......

Comment: Cast or convert? Method returns object, I don't see reason to cast it. For converting use Convert.ChangeType

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static T Cast<T>(object obj, Type castTo) 
{ 
     return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, castTo); 
}
```

An example works :

https://dotnetfiddle.net/JqFMds

Comment: If you instead of `dynamic`, pass `object` and do `T Cast<T>(object obj, Type castTo) { return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, castTo); }` then you don't need to return `dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the anwser

Comment: is there a way other than generics.

Comment: @NagasivaniSiddana : you can use this version : https://dotnetfiddle.net/E4ervV , with dynamic . But I think my answer is more elegant

Comment: It is showing an error that object should implement Iconvertable interface

Comment: @NagasivaniSiddana can you check your code because the method in the anwser doesn't need IConvertable interface. Look on the code dotnetfiddle, it works

Comment: I am using it for the user defined classes .i am trying change the derived type to base and it is me that error

Comment: This generic solution seems a bit weird - if you have the type `T` as a compile time value then what is the point of the `castTo` parameter?

Comment: @Thierry https://dotnetfiddle.net/x1BWB3

Comment: @NagasivaniSiddana : because of the user-defined typed, if you want to convert Devired to Program, you need to define the convertion of 2 types (by IConvertible interface) ....